# How do I display the city names and population of a selected country in my javascript AJAX code?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, xml

I am creating a webpage that displays the names of countries. A selected country should display the name and population of the 10 largest cities in a table. So far, when I select the country, it only displays the name with no additional information.

The name and the population of the top 10 largest cities in each given country should be displayed.

Here is my fullcode;

```js
 "use strict;"
  
    function displayUSAInfo() {
      document.getElementById("country_name").innerHTML="USA";
      const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("country_data").innerHTML = this.responseText;  
        const text=this.responseText;
        // const obj = '{"City":"", "Population":""}';

         const arry=JSON.parse(text);
        //  document.getElementById("country_data").innerHTML = arry[0];
        //  let table="<tr><th>City</th><th>Population</th></tr>";

        //  table+="<tr><td>" + "city1" +"</td><td>" + "population1"+ "</td></tr>";
      //   for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) { 
      //     table += "<tr><td>" + obj.City + "</td><td>" + obj.Population + "</td></tr>";
      //   }
        //  docoument.getElementById("country_data").innerHTML = table;
      }
      xhttp.open("GET", "usa.txt", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
       
     function displayCanadaInfo(){    
      document.getElementById("country_name").innerHTML="Canada";  
      const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onload = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("country_data").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
      }
      xhttp.open("GET", "canada.txt", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }

     function displayRussiaInfo(){      
       document.getElementById("country_name").innerHTML="Russia";
       const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("country_data").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
      xhttp.open("GET", "russia.txt", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
     
     function displayMexicoInfo(){      
       document.getElementById("country_name").innerHTML="Mexico";
       const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("country_data").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
      xhttp.open("GET", "mexico.txt", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
     
  </script>
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <header>
      <h1><strong>Using AJAX</strong></h1>
  </header>
  <br>
  <main>
    <div class="country_selection">
      <h3>Select a country to get data on their populous cities: </h3>
        <form>
          <input type="radio" name="country" value="usa" onclick="displayUSAInfo()"> USA
          <input type="radio" name="country" value="canada" onclick="displayCanadaInfo()"> Canada
          <input type="radio" name="country" value="russia" onclick="displayRussiaInfo()"> Russia
          <input type="radio" name="country" value="mexico" onclick="displayMexicoInfo()"> Mexico
        </form>
        <div id="country_name"></div>
        <table id="country_data"></table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Use the principle DRY whenever you can. Don't Repeat Yourself. I'd suggest producing the file-name dynamically instead of having different functions for each country.

Comment: What is the problem? Did you get errors in the console?

Comment: I got this error from the console;

 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/CS213/usamexico.txt' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

How can I fix this problem.?

Comment: This is a CORS problem. You should set up a `localhost server` and test your html file through the server, or upload it onto your site and test it. In short, you should use the `http` protocol rather than `file` when sending the request.

Answer (score 1):

Your http requests are structured correctly, as far as I can guess without much context. Here is a more complete version of your code, with an `onerror` function.

The most common error you probably will be getting is that you are testing this as a file, and not using a server or `localhost`. Therefore, the protocol is `file://` instead of `http`, and `CORS` blocks this request. Check your browser console for more.

The second source of error is that you have to make sure the file actually exists in the path where it is being searched for. This is the same directory where your `script.js` is found because you are using a relative path.

Anyway, here is the code:

```js
"use strict;"

function display_country_info(){
  let country_name = window.event.target.value;
  document.getElementById("country_name").innerHTML = country_name[0].toUpperCase() + country_name.substr(1,);
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onload = () => {
    document.getElementById("country_data").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
  xhttp.onerror = () => {
    document.getElementById("country_data").innerHTML = "<b style='color: red;'>There was an error. Maybe the file was not found, or you are not using the http protocol.</b>";
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", country_name+".txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="country_selection">
  <h3>Select a country to get data on their populous cities: </h3>
    <form>
      <input type="radio" name="country" value="usa" onclick="display_country_info()"> USA
      <input type="radio" name="country" value="canada" onclick="display_country_info()"> Canada
      <input type="radio" name="country" value="russia" onclick="display_country_info()"> Russia
      <input type="radio" name="country" value="mexico" onclick="display_country_info()"> Mexico
    </form>
    <div id="country_name"></div>
    <table id="country_data"></table>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you, edit it however you want. Accomplished by simple javascript.

```html
<html>
<body>
<br><b> Choose your favroite season: </b><br>
<input type="radio" name="season" id="summer" value="Summer"> Summer <br> 
<input type="radio" name="season" id="winter" value="Winter"> Winter <br> 
<input type="radio" name="season" id="rainy" value="Rainy"> Rainy <br>
<input type="radio" name="season" id="autumn" value="Autumn"> Autumn 
<br><br>     

<button type="button" onclick=" checkButton()"> Submit </button> 
    
<h3 id="disp" style= "color:green"> </h3>
<h4 id="error" style= "color:red"> </h4>
</body>

<script>
    function checkButton() {  
            var getSelectedValue = document.querySelector( 
                'input[name="season"]:checked'); 
              
            if(getSelectedValue != null) { 
                document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML 
                    = getSelectedValue.value 
                    + " season is selected"; 
            } 
            else { 
                document.getElementById("error").innerHTML 
                    = "*You have not selected any season"; 
            } 
        }  
    </script> 
</html>
```